# Github commit over SVN

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Today I switched from my free Github account to the Micro plan. Right after that I was no longer able to commit any of my Repros when entering my password. As I said before the switch from free to Mirco everything was fine, and the Update still works. Only when I try to Commit something it simply does not work.

When I'm trying to Commit my changes svn invokes the login dialog. When entering a nonValid password the dialog pops up again and when I repeat with my valid login data is only get the message that the Authorization was not Successful.

What am i doing wrong?

Using VS 2013 and SVN 1.8.5.25224 X64

*e*
Even with re-checkout a whole repro, the error still remains and a Commit is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the Support of github i got a partial working answer. They told me to create a PersonalAccessToken under

https://github.com/settings/applications

and use the token content as my password. which didn't work but after some Try-Error i figured out that i should use the token content as USERNAME and as PASSWORD simple nothing. Then i am able to submit via Subversion again.